# Check if website was opened from an embed browser

Tags: javascript, c#, security, authentication

I have a website and I need to check when this site opens from an embed browser.

I need to do a similar flow to Google Login. When Google Login  detect that the site is loaded from an embed browser then the user cannot authenticate.

[More info](https://www.zdnet.com/article/google-bans-logins-from-embedded-browser-frameworks-to-prevent-mitm-phishing/)

Answer (score 1):

This gives if embed or not

```js
  function isEmbed() {
        try {
            return window.self !== window.top;
        } catch (e) {
            return true;
        }
    }
console.log(isEmbed())
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But `isEmbed` works when executed from an iframe/frame..., I have a [CefSharp](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp) implementation, this is an embed Chromium in .NET app.